# Can't access shared drive when connecting over VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco, network-share, cisco-asa

I can ping all network devices but it doesn't seem that DNS is resolving their hostnames.
ipconfig/ all is showing that I am pointing to the correct dns server.
 
I can "ping "dnsname"" and it will resolve but it wont resolve any other names.
Split tunnel is set up so outside DNS is resolving fine

So one issue might be DNS but I have the IP address of the server share so I figure I could just get to it that way. example: \10.0.0.1\ well I can't get to it that way either and I get "the specified network name is no longer available" I can ping it but I can't open the share.

Below is the ASA config :

```
ASA Version 8.2(1)
!
hostname KG-ASA
domain-name example.com
names
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.0.253 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address dhcp setroute
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns domain-lookup outside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 10.0.0.101
 domain-name blah.com
access-list OUTSIDE_IN extended permit tcp any host 10.0.0.253 eq 10000
access-list OUTSIDE_IN extended permit tcp any host 10.0.0.253 eq 8333
access-list OUTSIDE_IN extended permit tcp any host 10.0.0.253 eq 902
access-list SPLIT-TUNNEL-VPN standard permit 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
access-list NONAT extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
ip local pool IPSECVPN-POOL 10.0.1.2-10.0.1.50 mask 255.255.255.0
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-621.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list NONAT
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 10000 10.0.0.101 10000 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 8333 10.0.0.101 8333 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 902 10.0.0.101 902 netmask 255.255.255.255
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL
aaa authentication http console LOCAL
aaa authentication serial console LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL
http server enable
http 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 inside
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set myset esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto dynamic-map dynmap 1 set transform-set myset
crypto dynamic-map dynmap 1 set reverse-route
crypto map IPSEC-MAP 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic dynmap
crypto map IPSEC-MAP interface outside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 65535
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
telnet timeout 5
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
ssh 70.60.228.0 255.255.255.0 outside
ssh 74.102.150.0 255.255.254.0 outside
ssh 74.122.164.0 255.255.252.0 outside
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns 10.0.0.101
dhcpd lease 7200
dhcpd domain blah.com
!
dhcpd address 10.0.0.110-10.0.0.170 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ntp server 63.111.165.21
webvpn
 enable outside
 svc image disk0:/anyconnect-win-2.4.1012-k9.pkg 1
 svc enable
group-policy EASYVPN internal
group-policy EASYVPN attributes
 dns-server value 10.0.0.101
 vpn-tunnel-protocol IPSec l2tp-ipsec svc webvpn
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value SPLIT-TUNNEL-VPN
!
tunnel-group client type remote-access
tunnel-group client general-attributes
 address-pool (inside) IPSECVPN-POOL
 address-pool IPSECVPN-POOL
 default-group-policy EASYVPN
 dhcp-server 10.0.0.253
tunnel-group client ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
tunnel-group CLIENTVPN type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group CLIENTVPN ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect icmp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
```

I'm not sure where I should go next with troubleshooting

nslookup result:
Default Server:  blahname.blah.lan
Address:  10.0.0.101

Comment: So does `ipconfig /all` show the VPN'd DNS or the general DNS? Also, what does `nslookup networkdevicename` show?

Comment: ipconfig/all shows VPN DNS under the cisco int and also my local dns under LAN int and nslookup shows the correct address. Is networkdevicename a linux command? I'm testing this on win 7.

Comment: @evolvd the `nslookup networkdevicename` was meant to be all one command. So use nslookup to try to lookup the name of one of your network devices (you didn't give any examples).

Comment: nslookup brings up: Default Server: blah.blah.lan Address: 10.0.0.101 - so then I typed in sharename and I got this response *** sharename.blah.lan can't find sharename: Query refused

Comment: Are you sure that folder is shared out?  Can you access C$ on the server?

Comment: at this point im not trying to get to a specific folder. If I was in this clients office I could type \\servername and the shares for the server would come up. I can't do that when I VPN in. I thought I could just \\server IP address and it would bypass the DNS issue but that wont work either... so there seems to be two problems.

Comment: I was thinking about this some more, and should have said something sooner.  Have you tried running wireshark?

Comment: Run it where and look for what?

Comment: Run it on your machine and attach to the VPN client NIC, and look for anything funky while trying to access the server.

Comment: Anything funky..? So much data gets captured it would be helpful to know maybe some filters I could apply. I don't think this a vpn issue any more so I'm going to accept an answer and open a new question dealing with  the fileshare. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was gonna say, your config looks good (EXCEPT TELNET! shame on you lol). What protocols have you thrown at your share to try and verify connectivity, i.e. ICMP, FTP, HTTP, EIEIO, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your VPN NIC as first priority in the network config.

http://theregime.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/how-to-setview-the-nic-bind-order-in-windows/

Comment: The cisco vpn client is already top on the list

Comment: hmmm, sorry then.  I knew the cisco clients used to have a problem with DNS that setting the binding order fixed.  Can you access any share?  Or other hosts via the hostname?

Comment: There is only this one share and I can't access it via IP or hostname. Thanks for sending the link though, at least I know about it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a VPN issue. The share is a samba share and I can see in its logs that I'm getting denied access. I'm opening another question to help with that issue.